# how to install firebase in windows?

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-tools

```
C:\Users\MOM>npm install -g firebase-tools
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
C:\Users\MOM\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase -> C:\Users\MOM\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\bin\firebase.js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ firebase-tools@8.7.0
updated 1 package in 103.544s
```

I'm getting the above error. please help me in this regard.

Comment: You've installed firebase-tools successfully. Error message is about a dependency used by firebase-tools

Answer (score 2):

If you're having trouble installing the Firebase CLI on Windows, I **highly** recommend using the pre-built binary. The steps according to the documentation are:

> To download and run the binary for the Firebase CLI, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Download the [Firebase CLI binary for Windows](https://firebase.tools/bin/win/instant/latest).
> 2. Access the binary to open a shell where you can run the firebase command.
> 3. Continue to [log in and test the CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#sign-in-and-test-cli).

Answer (score 0):

The install actually worked.  You can tell because the output told you that 1 package was updated.  Now you should be able to run it with `firebase --version`.

Answer (score 0):

You can Download Firebase Windows Binary
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli

> To download and run the binary for the Firebase CLI, follow these steps:
>
> Download the [Firebase CLI binary for Windows](https://firebase.tools/bin/win/instant/latest). Access the binary to
> open a shell where you can run the firebase command. Continue to [log
> in and test the CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#sign-in-and-test-cli).

the file have a name like:

> firebase-tools-instant-win.exe

you need to rename it to:

> firebase-win.exe

or you will get an error when running it:

[Error with wrong file name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGSY0.png)